# How To Get Select Option and checkbox Values

Tags: forms, yii, crud

My form have select option and check box field. i m not getting the values of those fields.

1)

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'vehicle_type',array(''=>'select',1=>'Tempo',2=>'Jeep',3=>'Lorry',4=>'Bus',5=>'Tipper',6=>'Tanker',7=>'Tractor',8=>'Pick up van'));?>
```

when select the options it will display 1,2 like .how do change it.

2)

```
echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'general_condition_of_vehicle', array('Ava fitting' => 'Ava fitted', 'Ava working' => 'Ava working', 'Brake Condition' =>'Brake Condition'));?>
```

For checkbox when i choose the options and hit submit button it doesnot accept it. gives a validation error.

Comment: please post your controller, model and view code...

Comment: I didn't modify anycodes on controller and models. <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'vehicle_type',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>2000)); ?> instead of text field i have used select option and checkbox..

Comment: As per your code `general_condition_of_vehicle` can accept text. Is this correct as per your db? What does the model rules say?

Comment: array('general_condition_of_vehicle', 'length', 'max'=>1000)..this is the rule i have written in model control and when i create a form it shows the following error **General Condition Of Vehicle is invalid.

Comment: check the posted value by inserting the following line at the top of the action method in your controller `CVarDumper::dump($_POST['ModelName']['general_condition_of_vehicle'],1,1);exit;` This will tell you if the result is a string or anything else that isn't acceptable.